# Links on Social Media/metadata

Tags: metadata, google-plus

I have done several searches trying to find a solution with no luck. I'm hoping someone here can help.

For a while I was having a problem with my links on Facebook not showing the thumbnail or the description to my blog posts. They just showed a standard description and always linked to my home page. I was able to fix that issue by changing the metadata to the following:

```
  <meta property="og:type" content="article" />
  <meta property="og:url" content="<?= "http://www.calsots.com".$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>" /> 
  <meta property="og:title" content="<?= urldecode($_GET['title']) ?>" /> 
  <meta property="og:description" content="<?= urldecode($_GET['description']) ?>" /> 
  <meta property="og:image" content="<?= $_GET['image'] ?>" />
```

Now, I'm having an issue with G+. When I post a link the thumbnail doesn't show and there is no description. Any thoughts on how to fix this? I do have additional metadata for G+.

```
   <meta itemprop="name" content="">
   <meta itemprop="description" content="">
   <meta itemprop="image" content="">
```

I have tried changing the content to calls, direct descriptions, I've left it blank and I even removed it but nothing is working.

Answer (score 1):

The markup for the Google+ fragment you've provided isn't a full schema.org microdata set. Although it provides the data, you haven't shown if the page itself is setup correctly to indicate the `itemscope` and `itemtype`. You should also avoid the meta tags themselves, if possible, instead indicating the `itemprop` attribute on existing page elements.

See http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=176035 for more information about microdata in general, http://schema.org/docs/gs.html#microdata_how for details about how to markup your page with microdata, and https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets for the structured data testing tool, which can help determine how Google sees your page.

Comment: What's really confusing me is that I'm using it on a wordpress site and I'm trying to add it to the header so that it applies to all the blog posts. Is this the wrong approach? I am going off of https://developers.google.com/+/web/snippet/ which provided the snippet with the meta tags.

Comment: That page doesn't show meta tags with itemprop attributes. It does suggest that the OpenGraph markup should be "good enough" to get your data, but that Schema.org data is preferred. (My experience has been that it sometimes gets the OG data wrong for Google+, but usually does well enough if you don't give it other data that may confuse it.) You've said that you had "removed it", meaning the <meta itemprop> entries completely?